# Can I upgrade directly to MacOS Monterey if I am using MacOS BigSur 11.0.1

Tags: macos, software-update, big-sur, monterey

I am using MacBook Air 2017
I have macOS BigSur 11.0.1 installed on my system and I have not updated my macOS to BigSur 11.6

[image: macOS BigSur Update]

and as Apple released the new macOS Monterey tomorrow so can I directly download macOS Monterey instead of downloading macOS BigSur 11.6 that takes 6.17 GB

[image: macOS Monterey]

And will skipping macOS BigSur 11.6 hamper my system?

Comment: Yes you can upgrade it, and no it does not hamper.

Comment: @Skye-AT so can I skip updates shown in 1st image and directly download Monterey??

Comment: @YashChitroda Yes. It likely includes the security updates that are part of the update in 11.6.1 anyway.

Comment: Yes. It just downloaded 11.6.1, not installed yet (as image says *Install Now*.) You can just skip it and upgrade to Monterey.

Comment: @Skye-AT Thanks for reaching so now I am looking forward to directly upgrade to Monterey for MacOS 11.0.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I wrote in the comment earlier; Yes, you can upgrade your MBA to Monterey from Big Sur 11.0.1 without any problem (At least for OS. Apps still should have to be compatible with Monterey.)

The first image you attached only says *Install Now*, which means it still not applied (or changed any of system files) to your MBA; it just downloaded update file for 11.6.1.

The only problem I could think of is, as I wrote earlier, the compatible of apps. I'm sure most of apps should work with Monterey, but some of apps still isn't optimized to Monterey. So, if you have any apps that is critical to your job/hobby/etc, I'd advise you to check it if it's compatible to Monterey.